# How can I permanently grant sudo access to a user?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo, visudo

I created a service to automaticle initialize some scripts for me, but when I try to run, they do not work very well... keep asking my sudo password.

I tried to add my user on sudors with sudo visudo, but nothing changed.

My commands:

```
sudo visudo
--changing the file
vitor ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
ctrl+x
y
```

Comment: Is there no space between `NOPASSWD:` and `ALL`. `visudo` works like vi, you save by typing `ESC` + `:wq`.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

@Vitor Felipe

your addition should work fine.

You have to start a new shell (a new terminal), or in some cases, logout and log back into your graphical environment, in order for the visudo changes to take effect.